# An error occurred while preparing SDK package Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) - Deprecated: Request failed with status code 403

Tags: android-studio, installation, haxm

I am trying to install in the Android Studio the : Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) - Deprecated
And I get this error, what can I do please?